# MDX where clause in subquery does not slice cube - how to understand?

Tags: ssas, mdx

This query gives me sales of one store:

```
select
[measures].[sales] on 0
from [MyCube]
where [store].[store].[042]
```

However, if I move the slicer to inside of the subquery, it gives me sales of all stores.

```
select
[measures].[sales] on 0
from (select
  from [MyCube]
  where [store].[store].[042]
)
```

How to understand the mechanisms behind this difference?
This is also noted in [this article](https://msbiworld.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/ssas-sub-select-vs-where-clause-3/), but without much explanation.

**----EDIT----:**

I tried various things and read around for a while. I'd like to add a question: is there a scenario in which the where clause in sub-select does filter the result?

This query gives me sales of all stores in state MI (store [042] belongs to MI):

```
select
[measures].[sales] on 0
from (select
  [store].[state].[MI] on 0
  from [myCube]
  where [store].[store].[042]
)
```

Thinking of 'inner query only filters if the filtered dimension is returned on an axis', the theory is proved wrong if I do this:

```
select
[measures].[sales] on 0
from (select
  [store].[state].members on 0
  from [myCube]
  where [store].[store].[042]
)
```

The sub-select still returns one state MI, but the outer query returns sales of all stores (of all states).

**----EDIT 4/13----**:

Re-phrasing the question in AdventureWorks cube with screenshot.
Query 1: sales of one store
Query 2: it returns sales of all stores if where clause is in the sub-select.
Query 3: the two answers I got suggested that we select the dimension in an axis - here is the result - we get all cities.

[image: AdventureWorks cube]

Comment: The way I use subselects is just `(SELECT blah ON 0, foo ON 1, bar ON 2 ..... FROM cube)` with as many axes as is required. I've never played with the `WHERE` clause - what does `msdn` say about this?

Comment: I've added a little more in terms of the WHERE clause to the bottom of my post.

Comment: hi - the script of the subselect of your second query is not valid - if you try running that independently it will fail as there are no axes in the SELECT

Comment: your third and fourth scripts do not specify a cube - so not sure how they are working at all?

Comment: if you add the cube into your third and fourth subselects then they are still not valid as you cannot use [Store] on rows or columns if it already in the Where clause.

Comment: @whytheq Hi if a select statement does not have an axis, it will return the default measure of all the default dimensions. It wouldn't fail. The difference is that the returned result does not have a header.

Comment: @whytheq and thanks I corrected the 3rd and 4th queries. I had to change the query because cube name reflects my company's business.

Comment: Did you try taking the subselect of Query3 and running it independently? It will fail. Why it doesn't fail once in the subselect Im unsure but maybe just add in `{} ON 0`. Also you have two scripts in this question with [Store] ON 0 and [Store] in WHERE clause - this will also fail, as the same dimension is not allowed on an axis and in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I'll add the the reason for this behaviour to my answer.

Comment: All of the above queries have only sales measure on 0. No '[Store] ON 0 and [Store] in WHERE clause' as you claim it. Also, the subquery without any axis does run independently. the 'select from [cube]' query can run on a cube in Microsoft AS. Are you using some other cube other than MS AS?

Comment: apologies - you're correct re. `select from [cube] where foo` - this returns a number

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other good references concerning sub-select and slicer debate:

http://bisherryli.com/2013/02/08/mdx-25-slicer-or-sub-cube/

https://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/free-video-on-subselects-in-mdx/

Chris Webb's video being located here:

https://projectbotticelli.com/knowledge/what-is-a-subselect-mdx-video-tutorial?pk_campaign=tt2014cwb

This should still leave an `All` member:

```
SELECT 
  [measures].[sales] ON 0
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
  FROM [MyCube]
  WHERE 
    [store].[store].[042]
);
```

...but the member `[All]` of the Store hierarchy will only now be made up of `[store].[store].[042]`.
You can see this by adding the Store hierarchy onto `ROWS`:

```
SELECT 
  [measures].[sales] ON 0,
  [store].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
  FROM [MyCube]
  WHERE 
    [store].[store].[042]
);
```

This is the `AdvWorks` version similar to the reference in your question:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Order Count]} ON 0
 ,[Subcategory].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
      [Subcategory].[Subcategory].&[22]
    } ON 0
  FROM [Adventure Works]
);
```

It returns the member from the sub-select and the `All` member adjusted to take account of the subselect:

[image]

In the references article why is the `[All]` less than the sum of the other two - this is not down to the subselect but is in connection with the measure that he has chosen `[Measures].[Order Count]` which is a distinct count. If you take away the subselect you see exactly the same behaviour of the All member being less than the sum of the other subcategory members (I've marked the point at which the total of the parts becomes higher than the All member):

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Order Count]} ON 0
 ,Order
  (
    [Subcategory].MEMBERS
   ,[Measures].[Order Count]
   ,bdesc
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

[image]

Order Count: on 1 order there might be several Product Subcategories - hence this behaviour.

---

Edit

This query of yours:

```
select
[measures].[sales] on 0
from (select
  [store].[state].members on 0
  from TestCube //<< added this!
  where [store].[store].[042]
)
```

This inner script is not valid? Using the same dimension on an axes and the WHERE clause is not valid:

```
select
  [store].[state].members on 0
from TestCube
where [store].[store].[042]
```

---

Edit2

An `mdx` script returns a cube, which may be sliced or not sliced, but nevertheless it returns a cube. The `WHERE` clause is used to slice the cube that is returned. If we were using a third party tool then the dimension added to the `WHERE` clause would go into a combobox - with say `Cliffside` selected. BUT the user could effectively select `Ballard` from that combobox - it is just a slicer. The `WHERE` clause is not changing the cube that is returned by the `mdx` script, it is just affecting what is displayed in the `cellset`.
`WHERE` is valid within a subselect. It is part of the definition:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487138.aspx
I've never found a use case for a subselect's `WHERE` clause.

---

Edit3

This link will explain things:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ccb66ac3-0f9a-4261-8ccc-b6ecc51b6f07/is-where-clause-pointless-inside-a-subselect?forum=sqlanalysisservices

As Darren gosbell says in the answer to this question:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487138.aspx it says that:
>
> The WHERE clause does not filter the subspace.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still trying to understand your answer. For starters, I added the store dimension to outer select query, and I get all the stores, not 'all member only made up by one store'.

Comment: strange - please detail and add screenshot to your original question

Comment: Sure... I'll get some screen caps on adventureworks cube when I get back to work on Monday :)

Comment: @kate1138 did Edit3 above answer your question?

Comment: @kate1138 no problem. I learned something new from your question in connection with using the WHERE clause. Apologies for "wasting your time".

Answer (score 1):

```
select
[measures].[sales] on 0
from (select
  from [MyCube]
  where [store].[store].[042]
)
```

The above query reduces the scope of *stores* just to the member `[042]`. Make note that sub-select is executed *before* the actual select. So, when it comes to the select, the engine just sees a cube which has all the members in all the dimensions; but only the member `[store].[store].[042]` in the store dimension. It's as if the cube has been kept intact every where else but *sliced off* on the `Store` dimension.

If you go a step ahead and add the `store` on to one of the axes, like

```
select
[measures].[sales] on 0,
[store].[store].members on 1
from (select
  from [MyCube]
  where [store].[store].[042]
)
```

you would see that although the member `[All]` appears in the output, it actually is just comprised of only one store.

In essence, the `[All]` is a special member which is calculated with respect to scope of the cube. It reflects the combined effect of all the members in the cube.

In SQL terms, it is similar to:

```
select sales, store as [All] from 
(select sales, store from tbl where store = '042') tbl
```

Even though you see `Sales----All`, it is but a reflection of sales for store `[042]`

Comment: (upped) looks like more effort ignored

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Maybe I'm not getting it right, but getting the store dimension in the outer query does give me all the stores, not just one store.

Comment: ....the point is that a where clause in a sub-select does not filter the sub-space: you can write WHERE in a sub-select, Microsoft have not added anything so that it throws an exception but it may as well throw an exception because it will not do absolutely no filtering. This _fact_ is stated in MSDN's definition of the sub-select.  Maybe they left the sub-select WHERE clause for future changes to MDX but currently it does nothing.